# AngularJS with Kendo/Bootstrap/JQuery/

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am researching to find which UI framework is good with AngularJS, in the basis Performance, Compatibility, Visual look and feel.

Can someone please suggest me to select the UI framework with AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

So far I can see that **UI Bootstrap** is the super cool and easy to use framework to work with AngularJS.

Please go through the amazing features of this framework [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

For developers using AngularJS, **Angular Material** is both a UI Component framework and a reference implementation of Google's Material Design Specification. This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on Material Design.

You can refer [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)